# Load specific html content via AJAX from a page that is loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to make ajax call to load some specific div to my webpage. But the content I wanna load is itself loaded via ajax, so I can't get the full html content as I want.

```
function loadajax(){  
$.ajax({ url: 'http://callcom-com-au.myshopify.com/products/repair',
    crossDomain: true,
    method:'post',
    dataType: 'html', 
    success: function(response) { 
      $('#customer_reviews').html(jQuery(response).find('.spr-header').html());
      $('.spr-icon').css('color','#f3b41b');
    }
   });
  }
$('document').ready(function(){
setTimeout(loadajax,10000);

});
```

Is there any workaround. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is 'http://callcom-com-au.myshopify.com/products/repair' external url (not the domain of your website)? What is the error you get?

Comment: target resource is not in my domain. Dats the reason

Comment: @plbsam I don't get any error, but the content is loaded partially, as the full content is loaded via ajax after sometime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply open this page http://callcom-com-au.myshopify.com/products/repair and firebug/google-chrome-web-tools etc. and click tab Network. Then grab direct link to content you want to get.